# In Minecraft version 1.13.2, is it possible to command a block that asks the player what command they would like to trigger in the chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a teleport elevator command, where you can go in and select one of many levels. To save space and not have a button or sign for each level, I thought it could show the options in chat like, "[1] [2] [3]" symbolizing level 1, 2, 3 and so on.

So, is there a way to set a command block to ask the player through chat which command they would like to trigger by chat or any other space saving means?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put a [click event](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text) of type "`run_command`" into a `tellraw` text.
This has the problem that it runs commands with the player's permission level, so if you want that to execute commands with higher permission levels, you have to use [`/trigger`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/trigger) and then let command blocks, functions, etc. run the command based on the score set by the `trigger` command.